# mock showing up as undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mocking, jestjs

Hi I trying to make two test for a function in my react app and from what I understand somehow my mock function is being turned into an undefined and I don't know why. I'm calling the mock function the exact same as in many of my other test in this app, but these two test aren't working.

my not working test

```
it('inTimeFrame() work', () => {
  const wrapper = shallow(<Reactpage />)
  wrapper.instance().fetchData = jest.fn()
  wrapper.instance().forceUpdate()
  wrapper.setState({'Date1':'2018-07-01','Date2':'2018-08-01'})
  wrapper.instance().inTimeFrame()
  expect(wrapper.instance().fetchData()).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
})

it('inTimeFrame() throw error3', () => {
  const wrapper = shallow(<Reactpage />)
  wrapper.instance().fetchData = jest.fn()
  wrapper.instance().forceUpdate()
  wrapper.setState({'Date1':'2016-07-01','Date2':'2018-08-01',
                    'getJson':[{'1':1},{'2':2}], 'fetching':true})
  wrapper.instance().inTimeFrame()
  expect(wrapper.instance().fetchData()).not.toHaveBeenCalled()
  expect(wrapper.state('error3')).toEqual(true)
  expect(wrapper.state('getJson')).toEqual({})
})
```

the function I'm trying to test

```
inTimeFrame = () => {
    var d1 = moment(this.state.Date1, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
    var d2 = moment(this.state.Date2, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
    var maxBack = moment().subtract(1, 'year')
    if (  d1.diff(d2, 'years') <= 1 && d1.isSameOrAfter(maxBack, 'day')){
        this.fetchData()
    }else{
        this.setState({"error3":true, "getJson":{}})
    }
}
```

the output of npm test

[image]

Does anyone know how to fix this so my mock aren't turned to undefined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`expect(...).toHaveBeenCalled` accepts a mocked function. You are passing `undefined`:

1. You created a mock function with `wrapper.instance().fetchData = jest.fn()`
2. Unless you tell it to, `jest.fn()` creates a function that now returns `undefined`.
3. You are calling `fetchData` and passing the *result* (`undefined`) to the expect function.

You need to change:

```
expect(wrapper.instance().fetchData()).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
```

To:

```
expect(wrapper.instance().fetchData).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
```

And make a similar change to your other test